# Connecting Outlook 2007 to Domino 6.5?

Tags: outlook, lotus-notes

Outlook (2007 now) is my favorite mail client and I would like to keep using it for both private and work emails. But with my new work, I discovered (with horror) that we have to use Lotus Domino and Lotus Notes 6.5 as client.

Is it possible to get my Lotus mails inside Outlook while maintaining my private POP mails in their existing PST ?

Here is the configuration:

- Lotus Domino server version is 6.5
- Outlook 2007 (fully patched) with a pst file created to handle private POP mail accounts.
- MS Office Outlook Connector for IBM Lotus Domino v2.0.4007.0

EDIT: Of course, I have tried to add the account directly using Tools ==> Account Settings ==> New ==> Other ==> Lotus Notes Mail, exit Outlook and re-open it. Then I get the following error:

> The set of folders cannot be opened. An unexpected error has occured.
>   MAPI was unable to load the information service nwnsp.dll. Be sure the service is correctly installed and configured.

(This also my first question to StackOverflow so it is my way to test the return of this site.)

EDIT 1/07/2009: As I have discovered that the POP/SMTP ports were opened, I have decided to use this method to retrieve and send emails, fully aware of the disadvantage of the methods but at leas,t I am now using Outlook as client.

Comment: I share your pain, fellow Notes user.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is to use Domino Access Manager for Outlook.

There is an IBM redbook that provides all the details here:

http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg246754.html

Abtract:

This IBM Redbook discusses IBM Lotus® Domino® Access for Microsoft® Outlook, the software solution that allows Outlook client users to easily access mail and calendar data that is stored on Lotus Domino servers.

If you want to improve the reliability and scalability of your messaging infrastructure and to add collaboration, upgrading from Microsoft Exchange to IBM Lotus Domino Access for Microsoft Outlook (DAMO) provides the solution. With DAMO, you have reliable, scalable, and secure Lotus Domino Messaging to Microsoft Outlook users without requiring users to change from the Outlook client -- users simply work with mail, calendar, and task data on Lotus Domino instead of Microsoft Exchange. Familiar Microsoft Outlook features are supported, including rich text, folders and Directory Catalog. Lotus Domino Access for Microsoft Outlook also gives Microsoft Outlook users the additional benefits of Domino Messaging features, including full text search capability for their mailbox and native support for Internet standards (SMTP/MIME and HTML).